# Why is חֲבַצֶּ֣לֶת traditionally translated as a "Rose" (וֶרֶד), instead of an "Onion" (בָּצָל)?

Tags: translation, song-poetry

In reference to the megillah שִׁ֥יר הַשִּׁירִ֖ים [Chapter 2 : verse 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the Ivri (עִבְרִי) word "חֲבַצֶּ֣לֶת" is translated as **Rose "וֶרֶד"**. - When using Google translate, **Rose and Lily (שֽׁוֹשַׁנַּ֖ת) are synonymous**, but it does not state Onion (בָּצָל) is synonymous with Rose.

שִׁ֥יר הַשִּׁירִ֖ים ch.2

> [1] "I am a rose of the-Sharon, a rose of the-valleys." (אֲנִי֙ חֲבַצֶּ֣לֶת הַשָּׁר֔וֹן שֽׁוֹשַׁנַּ֖ת הָֽעֲמָקִֽים)

**Why is "חֲבַצֶּ֣לֶת" traditionally translated as a "Rose" ( וֶרֶד ), instead of an "Onion" ( בָּצָל )?**

Comment: The commentators equate Chavatzelet with a rose (the JPS says "crocus") but only Rashi's comment has explanation ("Alternatively, a young rose is called חבצלת and requires the abundant sunshine of the mountains. A mature rose is called שושנה, and the climate of the valley is best suited for it. (Sefer Duda’im)"). The torah temimah discusses the etymology more thoroughly https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.2.1?lang=bi&with=Torah%20Temimah&lang2=en

Comment: חבצלת is not derived from בצל any more than גב (back) from חגב (locust)

Comment: שושנת העמקים חבצלת השרון

Comment: Because it's not an onion!

Comment: I think I may have heard this translated as a lilly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancratium_maritimum, assumes *chavatzeles* = lilly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rosends has already provided the main points in the comment, but I would add the following...

The Midrash in [Shir HaShirim Rabbah 2:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.2.1.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) demonstrates how the word can be seen as a contraction of two words, much like the Torah Temimah discusses. But crucially in the final definition that the Midrash provides it says:

> אֲנִי מַרְטֶבֶת כְּשׁוֹשַׁנָּה
>
> *I bloom like a lily*

So conceivably, the two words "חֲבַצֶּ֣לֶת" and "שֽׁוֹשַׁנַּ֖ת" are synonymous because they grow in the same way.